# how to create rules for old RewriteRule to new RewriteRule without losing traffic

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have old rewrite url now i want to change the pattern and don't want to lose traffic from google indexed pages.

**OLD RewriteRule and php code**

```
//php code
<?php echo SITE_URL .''. $rw['album_url'].'-album-1'; ?>

//output url
http://example.com/album-title-great-new-album-1

//.htaccess rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)-album-(.*)$ album.php?album_url=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

i want to change it to without losing traffic.

```
//php code
<?php echo SITE_URL .''.$rw['album_id'].'/album/'.$rw['album_url']; ?>

//output url
http://example.com/523/album/album-title-great-new
```

Comment: If you don't want to lose traffic, you should set up the old URL's as well but with a 301 redirect to the new URL for the same page.

Comment: its about 6000+ urls..

Comment: @Arman what is the old URL and what is new URL that you want?

Comment: this is the old url
http://example.com/album-title-great-new-album-1

New URL
http://example.com/523/album/album-title-great-new

but its 6000+ urls in the format..